# Does my wife need to sign IT-203 (NY state return) if I supply IT-203-C?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, new-york

I was preparing NY state return for 2012 using H&R Block TaxCut and I noticed a new option (never noticed before) for a joint return where only one spouse has income from NY source. I selected that option and as a result I was asked to supply IT-203-C to certify that I'm the only spouse with NY income. That form says that my wife cannot be required to sign the return although it's joint. So should or shouldn't my wife sign the return?

Answer (score 1):

She can, if she wants to take the liability. She cannot be required thought. If she does - it will be of her own free will and choice.